# Running a loop for a minute - Android

Tags: java, android, loops, calendar, while-loop

I was watching online java tutorial about loops. That created a loop that will run for one minute. In each loop the square root of a number is done, then this number increases by one. In theory this would serve to measure the speed of the device, because according to the potential of the device are made different number of repetitions of the loop.

The problem is I can not make this work in Android. This is my code:

```
package com.example.app;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView tv1, tv2;
    int index = 0;
    int  s, second, minute;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);

        //CURRENT TIME
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        second = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

        //TIME AFTER 5 SECONDS
        s = second + 5;

        tv1.setText("Processing...  Initial Time: " + minute + " minutes " + second + "seconds" );

        while (true){
            double x = Math.sqrt(index);
            index++ ;
            // each loop will check the until 5 seconds elapsed
            c = Calendar.getInstance();
            if (c.get(Calendar.SECOND) == s);{
                tv2.setText("\nDone! Final Time: " + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " minutes " + c.get(Calendar.SECOND) + "seconds\n" +
                index + " Loops in 5 seconds\n" +
                "checking boolean... " +c.get(Calendar.SECOND) + " = " + s);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the result:
[image]

Comment: As an aside, your loop won't stop if it starts where seconds >= 55 (because you'll then be checking for a seconds value >= 60).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (c.get(Calendar.SECOND) == s){
```

I have removed ";" symbol

Also note that long calcultions in main app thread will freezes it, so you should start background thread for your calculations.

Comment: Nice catch, I couldn't see it!

Answer (score 2):

remove the ; between your if and the {.

Answer (score 1):

You should not code such loops in `onCreate`, this blocks UI thread that will end up in ANR (Application Is not Responding) error.

You can use CountDownTimer for such purposes, or Handler with postDelayed use